# Can we use array as priority_queue element in C++?

Tags: c++

Consider following example:

```
priority_queue<int[3], vector<int[3]>, greater<int[3]>> pq;
pq.push({{2,3,4}}));
int * x=pq.top();
```

It says that no matching function found for push().

Of course, we can use a tuple to do the same thing. But I'm just curious can we use array directly.

Comment: Why people use `int[3]` in c++?

Comment: Use `std::array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `std::vector<int[3]>`.

`std::vector<T>` requires `T` to be [Erasable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements.general#15.6), which means that the expression

```
allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p)
```

is well formed.  When `A = std::allocator<int[3]>`, this tries to do

```
p->~T()
```

which is equivalent to

```
(*p).~T()
```

where `p` is of type `int(*)[3]` and `T` is `int[3]`.  Arrays are not allowed to appear in a pseudo destructor call: [[expr.pseudo]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.pseudo#2)

> The left-hand side of the dot operator shall be of scalar type. [...]

(Arrays are not scalar types.)

---

You can use `std::array<int, 3>` though.  It is compared in [lexicographical order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) by default.

Comment: would it be possible to write a custom allocator such that c arrays are Erasable (with that allocator) ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I guess [we can](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mOI6NfjuaNg8PUr0), in principle.  It would be a pain to use though - we can't resize the vector, for example, as arrays are still not MoveInsertible.

Comment: yeah I was expecting it to be pain. It was just curiosity. Came here from a almost dupe and my answer says just "not possible", now I wasnt sure if that is right, because Erasable merely requires `allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p)` not more