# Using C-style arrays in std::vector - MSVC bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I'm currently trying to get a legacy codebase to build under C++20, and I encountered something like this:

```cpp
size_t someCount; // value comes from somewhere else
…
std::vector<const char *[2]> keyValues(someCount);
```

I can't trivially change this to something like `std::vector<std:array<const char *, 2>>` because this is later passed to some API outside of my control. The above abomination compiles fine with Clang and GCC, and even MSVC as long as I don't enable C++20, but it breaks in MSVC in C++20, as you [can see here at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KcKKdoYbo).

I assume this is related to the [DefaultInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) requirement on `T` if the above constructor is used (which is indeed the only requirement [mandated by the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.cons#3)). According to cppreference (see previous link), STL implementations up to C++17 used placement new to default-construct the elements, and starting in C++20, `std::construct_at` is being used for `DefaultInsertable` types. This may trigger the regression from C++17 to C++20 for MSVC.

The [standard says](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#container.alloc.reqmts-2.1) that a type is `DefaultInsertable` if this expression is well-formed:

```cpp
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
```

So in my case, that would be:

```cpp
const char * dummy[2];
using Allocator = std::allocator<const char *[2]>;
Allocator a;
// This must be well-formed:
std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(a, dummy);
```

This [compiles fine and without warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/3P4bnacEe) in GCC, Clang and MSVC, so I'll go ahead and assume that `const char *[2]` is a `DefaultInsertable` type. But that means that the constructor call in my first example should compile.

Is this an MSVC bug?

The compiler error is:

```
C:/data/msvc/14.34.31931-Pre/include\xutility(218): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const char **' to '_Ty (*)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=const char *[2]
        ]

C:/data/msvc/14.34.31931-Pre/include\xutility(218): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or parenthesized function-style cast
C:/data/msvc/14.34.31931-Pre/include\xmemory(673): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty (*std::construct_at<_Objty,,0x0>(_Ty (*const )) noexcept)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=const char *[2],
            _Objty=const char *[2]
        ]
```

Comment: What's the story with the "API outside of my control"? Is it something that's explicitly demanding to get a `std::vector<const char *[2]>`, or no soup for you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik more or less. It's CORBA's ORB_init, which is declared roughly like this: `ORB_init(…, const char* options[][2]=0)`. The `std::vector` is used to dynamically build the argument. We could of course also manually allocate that with `new`, but I'd rather not make it worse…

Comment: All you need to do is allocate a single array full of `const char *[2]`s. Given the situation, I would not object, too much, to using `std::array`, and then using `reinterpret_cast` to make the whole problem go away.

Comment: I managed to extract the exact compiler error from the link, and added it to the question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You mean having a `std::vector<std::array<const char *, 2>>` and then `reinterpret_casting` its `data()` to `const char *[2]`? That has to be UB, right? This feels like a very clear violation of the strict aliasing rule. Also, we have no guarantees about the memory layout of `std::array`, right?

Comment: Actually, the layout of `std::array` is explicitly spelled out. There are some pretty good guarantees about it. This most likely violates strict aliasing, but I see it as the lesser of all evils, and this is what unit tests are for.

Comment: @LukasBarth: "*That has to be UB, right?*" ... so what?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*Actually, the layout of std::array is explicitly spelled out.*" Not well enough to make it guarantee-ably well-defined. `array` could have padding at the end. An `array<char, 2>` may be 4-bytes in size. You could `static_assert` to ensure that a particular `array` instantiation doesn't have padding though.

Comment: This question is tagged as `language-lawyer`, so 'This is UB, so what?' is not what I'm going for. I try to write well-formed C++ programs. Everything else is completely unmaintainable in my experience. YMMV.

Comment: libc++ also rejects this. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8e6jaTzfq)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Me81ar1GT `'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char **' to 'T (*)'`. Apparently `new T()` returns a `const char**` when `T` is a `const char*[2]`, which makes little sense to me, but is the crux of the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735065/vector-of-array-fails-to-compile

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before C++20, using array types in `std::vector` with the default allocator `std::allocator` was not supported, because `std::allocator::destroy` would try a simple (pseudo)-destructor call that is ill-formed for anything but class and scalar types. Thereby array types did not satisfy the *Erasable* requirement with the default allocator, which `std::vector` requires to be satisfied.

Since C++20 `std::allocator` is defaulted through `std::allocator_traits` to use `std::destroy_at` which in turn has a special case for array types that calls the destructor individually on each element. So *Erasable* is now satisfied with the default allocator.

However, C++20 also defaulted `std::allocator`'s `construct` through `std::allocator_traits` to use `std::construct_at`. In contrast to the old `std::allocator::construct`, `std::construct_at` returns the result of the placement-new expression and has its return-type declared as `T*` instead of `void`. `T*` is also the type of the first argument, i.e. `T` is the element type.

The issue here is that the placement-new expression inside `std::construct_at` will not return a pointer-to-array for array types, but instead return a pointer to the first element of the array. If `T` is an array type `U[N]`, then the return type of the new expression is therefore `U*`, not `U(*)[N]` as `construct_at` is declared to return. Therefore the `construct_at` instantiation is ill-formed and array types do not satisfy the *DefaultInsertable* requirement with the default allocator.

It is probably unintended that `std::construct_at` doesn't work with bounded array types. There is an open [LWG issue 3436](https://wg21.link/lwg3436) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably you should duplicate this answer here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612273/correct-way-to-work-with-vector-of-arrays, because it is asserted there that *You cannot store arrays in a vector*

Answer (score 4):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at
says that all it requires is `::new(std::declval<void*>()) T(std::declval<Args>()...)`, which [does compile in MSVC v19](https://godbolt.org/z/MMz84859T), so it appears that `std::construct_at` indeed has some bug where it accidentally coerces the `T*[]` into a `T**` and then can't convert it back.

Comment: Yes, that seems like the most likely variant. The standard does not formulate the requirement in terms of `std::construct_at` (but via the allocator as in my question), but I think that `std::construct_at` should have more or less the same behavior as `allocator_traits<A>::construct(…)`.